# Why does python unpack float act differently from 2.7.3 to 2.7.11

Tags: python-2.7

I don't understand why the following code gives me different results on 2.7.3 vs 2.7.11 unfortunately I'm stuck in a production environment that is 2.7.3 at the moment.

```
import struct

test = bytearray.fromhex("00804042")

#I get an error
#TypeError: unpack_from() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray 
#so I use buffer
result = struct.unpack_from('f', buffer(test), 0)

print result
```

In 2.7.11 I get 48.125, in 2.7.3 I get 1.1777e-38.  Also in 2.7.3 it would not accept a bytearray, hence the buffer(test) line.

Comment: Are the 2.7.3 and 2.7.11 Pythons running on the same machine?

Comment: no that could be it, one is an embedded box MIPS I think, the other is my intel dev machine.  But python doc did says this:  For the 'f' and 'd' conversion codes, the packed representation uses the IEEE 754 binary32 (for 'f') or binary64 (for 'd') format, regardless of the floating-point format used by the platform.   Maybe it's a byte ordering thing, something to test anyway

Comment: bah yeah that was it, should have thought of that...

Comment: Try unpacking with `"<f"` or `">f"`, to tell Python which endianness to use, rather than letting it use the system default. The two floats are the reverse of each other's bytes.